# Problema, con tipo archivo .txt fstream

Tags: c++

Hola mi problema es el siguiente, utilizo un readdir para leer todos los archivos en un directorio y lo hace a la perfeccion, lee todos sus archivos sin problema pero el problema radica cuando utilizo el ifstream para abrir e imprimir cierta informacion que hay dentro de este, lo extraño es que si imprime los archivos que no terminan en .txt como se muestra en la imagen. ¿alguna idea de como pueda corregir o el por que sucede esto?
[image: Los archivos .txt no abren pero los .cpp si]

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

void list_dir(string dir)
{
DIR * directorio;
struct dirent * elemento;
string elem;
if (directorio = opendir(dir.c_str()))
{ 
while (elemento = readdir(directorio))
{
elem = elemento->d_name;
cout<<elem;

ifstream file(elem.c_str());
string a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
file >>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h>>i;
cout<<"Nombre: "<<a<<"  "<<"Celular: "<<c<<"  "<<"Fecha de pago: "<<h<<" "
<<endl;

}            
}
closedir(directorio);
}

void init()
{
cout << "Ruta del directorio a listar: ";
string dir;
getline(cin, dir);
list_dir(dir);   
init();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
init();
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seguramente tiene que ver con que recorres el directorio al completo, ¿has intentado recorrer con filtros: `*.txt`?

Comment: Hola, podrías indicarme cómo lo podría hacer?

Answer (score 0):

Con la opcion que le he puesto en el if //marcado veras que lo primero que hace es leer si son archivos regulares y lo segundo he implementado una funcion para que terminen o contengan  al menos la terminacion .txt, ahi va:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <dirent.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool estxt(string s){
   return s.find(".txt");
}

void list_dir(string dir)
{
DIR * directorio;
struct dirent * elemento;
string elem;
if (directorio = opendir(dir.c_str()))
{ 
 while (elemento = readdir(directorio))
 {
  if(elemento->d_type==DT_REG and estxt(elemento->d_name)){//marcado
    elem = elemento->d_name;
    cout<<elem;
    ifstream file(elem.c_str());
    string a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i;
    file >>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g>>h>>i;
    cout<<"Nombre: "<<a<<"  "<<"Celular: "<<c<<"  "<<"Fecha de pago: "<<h<<" "<<endl;
   }
  }            
 }
closedir(directorio);
}

void init()
{
cout << "Ruta del directorio a listar: ";
string dir;
getline(cin, dir);
list_dir(dir);   
init();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
init();
system("PAUSE");
return 0;}
```